# Passing by value vs. Passing by reference

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

We were given this question on a quiz, and I'm having a hard time understanding it.

```
void EmptyStudent(Student s)
{
     s.Name = "";
     s.Major = "Undeclared";
     s.ID = "None";
}

EmptyStudent(objStudent);
```

"Assume the variable objstudent contains the name "John Doe", major is "IST", and id is "1001" before the call to the method, what will the contents of objStudent be after the call?"

Could someone explain this to me. I thought it would still be "John Doe", "IST" and "1001" since it is passing by value. Since it is passing by value, once you leave the method, wouldn't the variable stay the same?

Comment: @Claies primitives and `struct`s.

Comment: Don't tell people wrong knowledge.

Comment: sorry I knew that, just was a bit fast with my comment.  I don't see structs used very often, they tend to skip my mind... either way, I removed the incorrect comment.

Comment: Your question is missing information. Is it a `struct` or a `class`? Without that information, there is no definite answer. You should probably leave a note to the creator of your quiz, as it's a bad question

Comment: I'm going to assume its a class. But what I wrote above is all we were given for the question.

Comment: Student object didn't change outside the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the values changed, I am assuming that `Student` is a class and not a struct.

Classes are reference types. When you pass them to methods, you are passing a reference to the same object.

You need to think of `s` and `objStudent` as two different references pointing to the same object.

Structs behave differently, when you pass a struct to a method, a clone of the struct is created and passed to the method.

Please note that if you changed your method to this:

```
void EmptyStudent(Student s)
{
     s = new Student();
     s.Name = "";
     s.Major = "Undeclared";
     s.ID = "None";
}
```

Then the contents of `objStudent` would not have changed. This is because `s` and `objStudent` are two different references that are now pointing to two different objects.

To make `objStudent` and `s` the exact same references (like two aliases for the same reference), then you need to pass by reference like this:

```
void EmptyStudent(ref Student s)
{
     s = new Student();
     s.Name = "";
     s.Major = "Undeclared";
     s.ID = "None";
}

EmptyStudent(ref objStudent);
```

In this case, after the method call, `objStudent` would be pointing to the newly created object and thus will have its contents changed.

Comment: This not really true. The sample code does pass by value, but it's the value of the address to the object. Calling it pass-by-reference is quite misleading here. Passing by reference is strictly with "&" operator.

Comment: @Krypton The '&' operator? Only for unmanaged types. In C#, there's the `ref` keyword.

Comment: @Krypton, where am I calling it "passing by reference"? do you mean in my `ref` example?

Comment: Yeah, actually, I was thinking it as C++. But it is the same concept though.

Comment: @Krypton, When you use `ref`, you are passing by reference. Take a look at this [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have ref, you definitely do not pass-by-reference.

Comment: Sure. I didn't say anything to the contrary.

Comment: However you said "When you pass them to methods, you are passing a reference to the same object.", it sounds like "pass-by-reference"

Comment: reference in this case, means "a variable of reference type"

Comment: @Krypton `ref` and pointers are not really the same concept. They achieve similar results in two very separate ways. The fact you're not copying memory is a side effect.

Comment: @Qix "ref and pointers are not really the same concept": that is true. The question has nothing to do with ref, and thus nothing related to pass-by-reference. "They achieve similar results in two very separate ways.": not true. The effects are different.

Comment: @Krypton similar != same